# javascript event running when the mouse is over elements created by another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

This function create_canvas_card() creates a box with smaller boxes in it. How do I get it to call the function card_mouseover() whenever the mouse is over one of the boxes?

```
 function create_canvas_card(card_data, each_card){//where card_data is an element/object and each_card is an int
  click_canvas_card_x = 10, click_canvas_card_y = 10;//these are set elsewhere
  image_id = $(card_data.node).data('card')
  click_canvas_cards[each_card] = click_canvas.rect(click_canvas_card_x, click_canvas_card_y, 40, 40).attr('fill', 'url(/images/thumbnails/image'+ image_id +'.jpg)');

//my attempt      
$(card_data.node).bind('mouseover', function(e){
    var card = cards[$(this).data('card')];
    card_mouseover(card);
  });

//another attempt
//click_canvas_cards[each_card].mouseover(click_canvas_card_mouseover(card_data.node));
}
```

which is called from this loop

```
      for(each_card in cards_to_create_for_click){
        var card_data = cards_to_create_for_click[each_card];
        create_canvas_card(card_data, each_card);
      }
```

So far neither's worked.

Comment: its not clear to me whether you mean mousover over one of the larger boxes or smaller ones. Whatever, I'm just wondering why not add a Raphael mouseover handler to each card when created ? I suspect a jsfiddle would help to highlight the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Raphael's built in Element.hover() method.

[Element.hover](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.hover)

I've made a quick little fiddle to show you it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arn6z/)

For your example, I imagine you'd want to change your function to something like this:

```
 function create_canvas_card(card_data, each_card){
     click_canvas_card_x = 10, click_canvas_card_y = 10;//these are set elsewhere
     image_id = $(card_data.node).data('card')
     click_canvas_cards[each_card] = click_canvas.rect(click_canvas_card_x,      click_canvas_card_y, 40, 40)
     .attr('fill', 'url(/images/thumbnails/image'+ image_id +'.jpg)')
     .hover(function(){
         //Do something on hover
     });
```